# Flutter Error : The connection errored: The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates an error on the network laye

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

When I add a new value like account-type to the header I get the following error from the dio library

> DioExceptionType.connectionError
> ║  The connection errored: The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates an error on the network layer.

```
return await _dio.get(
  "payment/test/",
  options: Options(headers: {
    'account-type': 'master',
    'Authorization': authorize.user.access,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  }),
);
```

Comment: It more likely shows a CORS error. Use the browser's Dev Tools > Network tab to view the underlying error.

Comment: Hi,
Not related to your question, but I got the same error when testing my app on chrome. I've had this problem when using API's and testing app on browser. But when I tested those apps on my phone it worked.